# How are resources included in targets that are managed with Swift Package Manager 4?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a test target defined in my Package.swift file, and this test target requires some JSON files necessary for stubbing network responses while running acceptance tests in order to run.

`swift build` succeeds in building the main target, and `swift test` similarly succeeds in building the test target, but the tests fail as the necessary resources are not found when loading them is attempted.

How can I specify that these JSON resources are required build resources when using `swift build` and `swift test`.

Here is my Package.swift file:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyTarget",
    products: [
        .library(
          name: "MyTarget",
          targets: ["MyTarget"])
    ],
    targets: [
      .target(name: "MyTarget"),
      .testTarget(
          name: "MyTestTarget",
          dependencies: ["MyTarget"])
    ]
)
```

Comment: Managing resources with the Swift package manager is currently discussed on swift-evolution: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170925/039907.html

Comment: @MartinR I think it is a duplicate. How can I mark my question as a duplicate?